# first column of a row to bottom side on mobile view boostrap 3

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have two columns in a row.

```
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-2">
         I want this column in bottom side on mobile.
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-8">
         I want this column in top side on mobile.
      </div>
   </div>
```

When I visualize this on my laptop, they are in left and right side respectively. When I watch the page on my mobile phone I see first column on top of the web page.

I want to change the order, **first column left** side on **laptop** and **bottom side** on **mobile phone** **instance of** **first column** that is **left side** on **laptop** and **top side** on **mobile phone**.

I want to keep the laptop aspect, only change mobile phone view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:

```
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-push-2">
        I want this column in top side on mobile.
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-2 col-lg-pull-8">
        I want this column in bottom side on mobile.
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks @gluecksmelodie for documentation.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the documentation of Bootstrap 3's grid system:

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

By adding the `*-lg` classes you have only specified how your page should behave on a large screen.

You probably want to add the `*-xs` classes for defining the columns in the smartphone widths. You can keep the `*-lg` classes just as they are now.

Furthermore, for changing the order of columns in different widths, bootstrap provides `*-push` and `*-pull` classes, see here: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-column-ordering

Answer (score 1):

<del>add class to the larger div `.pull-left`, and smaller div `.pull-right`</del>

```
<div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-2 pull-right">
         I want this column in bottom side on mobile.
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-8 pull-left">
         I want this column in top side on mobile.
      </div>
   </div>
```

<del>This will float the second larger div to the left, and thus in the mobile view, where .col-lg-8 is not applicable, will bring it on top</del>

---

**Edit:** As this answer creates a gap between two divs, because there are only 10 columns utilized

You will need to change your html see this http://jsfiddle.net/53u69ama/1/

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-8 col-xs-12 ">
         I want this column in top side on mobile.
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-12 ">
         I want this column in bottom side on mobile.
      </div>

   </div>
```

---

**Edit 2:**  you can also change the top position using `position` style, but this will require you to set the static top for one `div`. Or you may change it using javascript dynamically.

see this http://jsfiddle.net/53u69ama/2/

Comment: It does the opposite I want. It changes left and right place ( I dont want to change it). I want to change only top and bottom place.

Comment: it does not work for me. I want something like pull-right you wrote, but for first colum pull-down, and second column pull-up.

Comment: Thank you @Naeem Shaikh , I have learned about you told me for another stuffs :). You can see the solution is almost you wrote at beggining.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
<div class="row">
    <!-- this is visible if view is all less lg (on top) -->
    <div class="device-xs visible-xs device-sm visible-sm device-md visible-md">
        <div>
            Content to view 2.
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2">
        Content to view 1
    </div>
    <!-- this is visible when view is lg (in right) -->
    <div class="col-lg-8 device-lg visible-lg">
        Content to view 2.
    </div>
</div>
```

Note that you will have to copy "Content to view 2." twice.